# How can I extract coordinates from GeometryArray or LineString?

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to measure the minimal distance between a point(with coordinate) and a line(which has numerous points-or-coordinates within several linestrings) in geojson file I have.(used geopandas to load file)

```
I will give an example of geojson data here
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "N02_001": "23", "N02_002": "5", "N02_003": "沖縄都市モノレール線", "N02_004": "沖縄都市モノレール" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 127.67948, 26.21454 ], [ 127.6797, 26.21474 ], [ 127.67975, 26.2148 ], [ 127.68217, 26.21728 ], [ 127.68357, 26.21862 ], [ 127.68394, 26.21891 ], [ 127.68419, 26.21905 ] ] } },
```

and loaded data is

```
      N02_001 N02_002     N02_003         N02_004                                           geometry
0          23       5  沖縄都市モノレール線       沖縄都市モノレール  LINESTRING (127.67948 26.21454, 127.67970 26.2...
1          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.29139 40.33740, 141.29176 40.3...
2          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.27554 40.23936, 141.27567 40.2...
3          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.28659 40.26092, 141.28538 40.2...
4          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.29082 40.28615, 141.29089 40.2...
```

I was tried to draw only coordinate part by split every geometry part of records to make it simple to calculate with arrays. - but it wasn't work since every record is linestring or geometry array.

To find other ways, I read several articles on google and QnAs here but I couldn't find any hints from them except 1 attribute ; distance(other) written here(http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#attributes).

I guess I could get the minimum distance from the line and certain point if I can make certain point to form of geometric point.(but have no Idea how to do that for now)

I'm so sorry I have few codes to show you.
There are only 3parts of code I have now. 
read file, try to split(didn't work), slicing GeoSeries by column(sliced objects are arrays of LineString or GeometryArray)

please give me some advice.

```
filename = "N02-18_RailroadSection.geojson"
linename = "総武線"
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
#load file
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(fn)
#draw records have certain value ; line name
all_wthcl = gdf1[gdf1.N02_003==linename]
```

Comment: As you mention yourself, geopandas provides a `distance()` method. Is this method not giving the result you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I faced the problem on making object which I could use for distance() method. I tried to making "Point" object for that but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code of what you tried?